# Did the CIA sell illegal drugs in the US in order to fund anti-communist Dictators in South America?

Tags: united-states, recreational-drugs, cia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did the CIA sell drugs in the US?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/did-the-cia-sell-drugs-in-the-us)

I've heard this many times from various sources.  I've heard it referenced to the crack epidemic in the 80s. I've heard it mentioned in connection with a news story that got buried about it happening again in the 90s (from a Pulitzer winning reporter).  I've heard that there was a trial in which it all came out, but that it got ignored.  Does the historical record support this?  Did it happen?  Or is this just a conspiracy theory?

Comment: This answer is kinda.  The CIA did not have agents or assets actually selling the drugs in the US.  But they were selling the drugs to cartels that were bringing it into the US.  Then using those funds to support the Contras.

Comment: This should really go to Skeptics SE

Comment: Where's the line between Skeptics and history?  Seems like it can be pretty blurry to me, depending on the topic.